# How to use in Julia a Python package that is not available in Anaconda and needs to be installed via pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, julia, pycall

I use Julia 1.6.0 (beta as of today) and would like to use a Python package `plfit` via `PyCall`.

Unfortunately, `plfit` is not available in Anaconda and hence I cannot install it using Conda module:

```
julia> using Conda

julia> Conda.add("plfit")
[ Info: Running `conda install -y plfit` in root environment
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - plfit

...
```

How can I install this package from Julia?

Comment: Ser also the build script of the OdsIo.jl package.

Comment: Yes this is very useful. However as of today: (1) pip is included with PyCall so it seems no installation actions are required here. (2) If pip is missing I would definitely install pip via ```Conda.runconda(`install -c anaconda pip `)```. (3) I am using `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` and find that having Python packages in `--user` environments is usually source of problems (Python's package management robustness is not any close to that of Julia).  Again this is just my personal view on that :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can run `pip` from Julia via the `PyCall` module.

Additionally, the package `plfit` has a reference to a `cython` package that is not present in Python in-built Julia and does not get installed automatically. Hence you need to do:

```
using PyCall
run(`$(PyCall.python) -m pip install --upgrade cython`)
run(`$(PyCall.python) -m pip install plfit`)
```

Now the `plfit` package will be available for use from Julia:

```
julia> plfit = pyimport("plfit");

julia> x=rand(1000);

julia> myplfit = plfit.plfit(x)
PYTHON plfit executed in 0.064029 seconds
xmin: 0.397582 n(>xmin): 625 alpha: 2.92546 +/- 0.0770183   Log-Likelihood: 36.3511   ks: 0.197384 p(ks): 4.09676e-22
PyObject <plfit.plfit.plfit object at 0x0000000064871A90>
```

Finally, note that sometimes some packages installed this way might have problems finding binary Python dependencies (not the case with plfit). In that case you need to add the folder `%HOMEPATH%\.julia\conda\3\Library\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable (replace `%HOMEPATH%\.julia` with `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` or an appropriate system path depending on your configuration and platform).

Comment: This is a very useful tip. I often forget how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pip also with Conda.jl (comes with PyCall):

https://github.com/JuliaPy/Conda.jl#conda-and-pip